# Use Retrofit methods more expressive way

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I want to make `void enqueue(Callback<T> callback);` method invocation code block more expressive, Here is what I have an usually

```
request.enqueue(object : Callback<MyModel> {
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
           //
      }

      override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyModel>?, response: Response<MyModel>?) {
           //
      }
 })
```

And what I want and mean is that, to change this code blocks more cleaner way and remove those **override, object, Callback** keywords and do something like that:

`request.enqueue({throwable, response -> })`

I think it could be improved somehow using extensions and higher-order functions. Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: Are you using RetroLambda plugin?

Comment: Nope, I'm using Kotlin

Comment: I think with Kotlin you can still use Lambda expressions. Please check, I think that is what you seek.

Comment: @DavidK the whole point is that `Callback` is not a functional interface, so it cannot be expressed as a lambda.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

this is how i do it with extension function and a class

```
fun<T> Call<T>.enqueue(callback: CallBackKt<T>.() -> Unit) {
    val callBackKt = CallBackKt<T>()
    callback.invoke(callBackKt)
    this.enqueue(callBackKt)
}

class CallBackKt<T>: Callback<T> {

    var onResponse: ((Response<T>) -> Unit)? = null
    var onFailure: ((t: Throwable?) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
        onFailure?.invoke(t)
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
        onResponse?.invoke(response)
    }

}
```

then you can use it like this

```
request.enqueue {

    onResponse = {
        // do
    }

    onFailure = {
        // do
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with any interface?

Answer (score 15):

Given the following function:

```
fun <T> callback(fn: (Throwable?, Response<T>?) -> Unit): Callback<T> {
    return object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: retrofit2.Response<T>) = fn(null, response)
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) = fn(t, null)
    }
}
```

You can use this with Retrofit like this:

```
request.enqueue(callback({ throwable, response ->
 response?.let { callBack.onResponse(response.body() ?: RegisterResponse()) }
 throwable?.let { callBack.onFailed(throwable.message!!) })
```

Alternately, you can define this other version of callback:

```
fun <T> callback2(success: ((Response<T>) -> Unit)?, failure: ((t: Throwable) -> Unit)? = null): Callback<T> {
    return object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: retrofit2.Response<T>) { success?.invoke(response) }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) { failure?.invoke(t) }
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
request.enqueue(callback2(
                { r -> callBack.onResponse(r.body()) },
                { t -> callBack.onFailed(t.message) }))
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: In your second version of the callback, could the `?` removed at the end of `fun <T> callback2(success: (Response<T>) -> Unit, failure: (t: Throwable) -> Unit): Callback<T>? {`? Or can the callback be null? I'm getting a warning there "Expected type does not accept nulls in Java, but the value may be null in Kotlin"

Comment: That's what you get for writing code without testing it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I used an extension function on `Call` to write an expressive and generic `enqueue` method.

```
fun<T> Call<T>.onEnqueue(actOnSuccess: (Response<T>) -> Unit, actOnFailure: (t: Throwable?) -> Unit)   {
    this.enqueue(object: Callback<T>    {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable?) {
            actOnFailure(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: Response<T>) {
            actOnSuccess(response)
        }
    })
}
```

This can then be used as:

```
request.onEnqueue    {
    actOnSuccess = {
        doOnSuccess()
    }
    actOnFailure = {
        doOnFailure()
    }
}
```

Within the actOnSuccess and actOnFailure blocks of code, **`it`** shall refer to the `Response` and `Throwable` objects respectively, and can be leveraged accordingly. For example, within the actOnFailure code block -

```
actOnFailure = {
        doOnFailure()
        //it.message //'it' refers to the Throwable object.
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is this (this is Java as I don't know much Kotlin, but that should be pretty similar):

```
public class CallbackWrapper<T> implements Callback<T> {
    private Wrapper<T> wrapper;

    public CallbackWrapper(Wrapper<T> wrapper) {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        wrapper.onResult(t, null);
    }

    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        wrapper.onResult(null, response);
    }

    public static interface Wrapper<T> {
        void onResult(Throwable t, Response<T> response);
    }
}
```

Which you can use as:

```
call.enqueue(new CallbackWrapper((throwable, reponse) - > {...}));
```

**update solution for kotlin:**

Based on [this](http://quest.sitehome.info/converted-java-class-file-to-kotlin-makes-compilation-error/), the `CallBackWrapper` looks like this:

```
typealias wrapper<T> = (t: Throwable?, response: Response<T>?) -> Unit

class CallbackWrapper<T>(val wrapper: wrapper<T>) : Callback<T> {
   override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable?) = wrapper.invoke(t,null)
   override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: Response<T>?) = wrapper.invoke(null, response)
}
```

and use it the same as Java.

Comment: Nice solution, also add <T> to the Wrapper inside the constructor for explicitly return type

Comment: Thank you so much 
Perfect answer for both Java and Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension function like this

```
inline fun <T> Call<T>.addEnqueue(
    crossinline onSuccess: (response: Response<T>) -> Unit = { response: Response<T> -> },
    crossinline onFail: (t: Throwable) -> Unit = { throwable: Throwable ->}
):Callback<T> {
    val callback = object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            onFail(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            onSuccess(response)
        }
    }
    enqueue(callback)
    return callback
}
```

and use it like this in your activity or fragment

```
 service?.fetchUser()?.addEnqueue(
            onSuccess = {
                doOnSuccess(it)
            },
            onFail = {
                doOnFail(it)
            }
    )
```